# UIButton Subclass @IBAction not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I created a sub class for a UIButton so I could get an animation effect on tap, the effect works, what doesn't work is when I try took hook it up to a @IBAction in my view controller. The function isn't getting called. I have the sub class set as the buttons class in my scoreboard. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class SpringyButton: UIButton {

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {


            self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.8, 0.8, 1)


            }, completion: nil)

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {


            self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1) 


            }, completion: nil)

    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {


            self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)


            }, completion: nil)

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {


            self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)


            }, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

and my IBAction in my ViewController:

```
@IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("go")
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this, any ideas?

Side Note: I've read that subclassing a UIButton isn't such a great idea, would it be better to subclass UIView and hook that up with a tap gesture recognizer?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't subclass UIButton to do this. I'd just add it as part of the action or something.

Comment: @Fogmeister tried that, the animation doesn't work properly as an action

Comment: You can absolutely do this as normal actions :D You just need to add the actions for `touchUpInside`, `touchDownInside`, etc... BTW, I'd transform the button itself not the button's layer.

Comment: I would not put any animation into any `–touched...` method... that is a kinda weird approach.

Comment: @holex so where should i put it? Doesn't work in a tap gesture recognizer. The button is supposed to scale down on tap and scale back when the finger is lifted.

Comment: @Yismo, for that feature you should take a look on how you can implement an action for `UIControlEventTouchDown`, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` events instead.

Comment: @holex how would I implement that?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you just override the touch events. You have to call super after overriding the function. For example in the `touchesBegan` function below:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

            self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.8, 0.8, 1)


     }, completion: nil)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

like this you have to add super to all of your touch events that you override. If you encounter any problem please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Interface Builder only uses UIButton. So subclassing won't really work. If you really want to use your custom class, you can programmatically create it.

```
let myButton : SpringyButton = SpringyButton()
```

Let me know if that works and/or if that's what you were looking for!